# Does Changing Production Transfer Hammers?

Tags: civilization-5

Civilization V is really kicking me hard this time around. Was an old-pro at Civ IV but this one's a completely different beast.

Anyway, back in Civ IV, when you changed production on a unit/building/wonder, you would keep some of those hammers, letting them transfer over to your new project. Great when you were beat to a wonder. However, with Civ V, it doesn't appear to be the case. Do hammers transfer at all if you change production?

Mostly concerned about wonders as I have a tendency to pick the wrong ones. And does anyone know of a mod that might fix this?

Comment: When you are beaten to a wonder, you get some form of recompense in money. When you switch construction between buildings, the expended hammers hang on in production of the initial building so it retains progress if you continue building it. (90% certain this is the case, will add as answer when 100%)

Comment: @shanodin I think that's correct as well. I vaguely remember some sort of decrease over time for the hammers the longer you keep them hanging around. I may be mistaken, though.

Comment: @shanodin It certainly is. I'll leave the answer to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are beaten to a wonder by another player/AI, you get some form of recompense in money - in face, you get more gold than if the produced hammers had been put into 'producing' gold in the city.

When you switch construction between buildings, the expended hammers hang on in production of the initial building so it retains progress if you continue building it. If for example, you're building a settler, but suddenly realise you need a warrior or you're doomed, you can switch to produce the warrior then switch back to the settler, and the settler will still be part-way through construction.

As for @rikitikitik's comment, I can neither confirm or deny whether there is any degradation of hammers over time.

Comment: Rikitikik is correct, though I don't know the formula for the decay.

Comment: I don't recall the formula for decay, but I do remember it starts after 50 turns, so there's usually plenty of time to go back to previous construction.

Comment: @shanodin What happens if you completely remove a unit/building from your city's queue (ie delete it)? Does the progress get saved even if you no longer have it as part of the city's production or is it turned into gold?

I believe you've answered this but the idea came into my head that you could completely remove items from your queue and wasn't sure if the same rules applied.

Comment: @redknightalex I'll see if I can find out or do some testing and edit it into my answer. Also if you think my answer is sufficient as it is, please mark it as accepted :) otherwise please do so if I can add the extra info.

Comment: @shanodin Accepted your answer. :) It definitely helped. (I'm just a bit slow now as I'm doing this at work and a new user.) If you do find anything interesting from your testing I would be interested to hear it. Civ games have been anything but simple.